# Python Error: "IndexError: list index out of range" while looping though list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, variables

I am looping through a list, and I get this error:

```py
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```py
    def get_clients_online(self):
        clients = []
        clients_time_online = []

        for _, _, file in os.walk(self.online):
            clients.extend(file)
            with open(self.online + file[0], "r") as f:
                clients_time_online.append(f.read().replace("\x00", ""))

        return clients, clients_time_online

    def check_online_clients(self):
        clients, clients_time_online = self.get_clients_online()

        for _ in range(10):
            for i, v in enumerate(clients):
                _, time_online = self.get_clients_online()
                print(i)
                print(time_online, clients_time_online)
                if time_online[i] != clients_time_online[i]: # This is where the error is happening.
                    client_name = v.split(".")[0]
                    client_num = v.split(".")[0].split("-")[2]
                    print(f"{client_name} (Client {client_num}): ONLINE")
                    clients.pop(i)
                    clients_time_online.pop(i)
            if clients == []:
                break
            time.sleep(1)
        
        if len(clients) > 0:
            for i, v in enumerate(clients):
                client_name = v.split(".")[0]
                client_num = v.split(".")[0].split("-")[2]
                print(f"{client_name} (Client {client_num}): OFFLINE")
        else:
            print("All clients are ONLINE")

        print()
```

The error is happening on this line:

```py
if time_online[i] != clients_time_online[i]:
```

It is the first "if" statement in the "check_online_clients" function.

Also, in the "get_clients_online" function, "self.online" is just reffering to the directory used for "os.walk" to loop through the files.

Comment: The index `i` is out of range for the `time_online` and/or `clients_time_online` lists.

Comment: Since we don't know what these lists are, how can we know why at least one of them doesn't have the length that you expect it to have? If you want help, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: First, Because you are giving `time_online` and `clients_time_online` an index `i`, make sure that the type of them both is list. Then make sure before you call them in that row, they already have that index and for example, they are not just empty lists.